# How do I handle suggested edits updating an outdated answer?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

How do I handle [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26723267) suggested edit?

The original answer was written in 2013 and the method used was deprecated in 2017.

Is approving this edit a "conflict with author's intent"?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I would reject an edit that edits code to "update" it.

I'm fine with edits that fix *typos* in code in *answers*, since you can assume it was not the author's intention to have wrong code in their answer. (Editing code to fix typos is *not* OK in questions, as that might hide mistakes, and finding mistakes is the whole point of asking a question). However, modifying code in this way is too far.

Some people are still using older versions of a library/framework, so that answer shouldn't be eliminated outright.

If you were going to edit an existing answer to bring it into compliance with a later version of the library/framework, then the better way to do that would be to add a *separate* section, clearly calling out which version of the library/framework your update applies to, leaving the original answer intact.

But it's generally even better to just post a new answer.

Comment: What if the question is old with 10+ answers? The newer (updated and correct) answer would go all the way to the bottom and probably won’t help a lot (and might not even be visible to point out the outdated accepted answer).

Comment: @HarshalParekh [that's a valid concern](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=outdated+answer). But then, it's actually expected for readers to read all the answers, not only the accepted/highest-voted answer.